# Predefine Collection Object VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure if I want a collection object or use dictionary object. I've used PHP associate arrays before, and I want to do that in VBA. For instance, here's some PHP code:

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'email' => 'john@example.com'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'Jane Doe',
        'email' => 'jane@example.com'
    ),
);
```

This is essentially what I want to do in VBA. I'd like to predefine it first if possible. So unlike in the example above, I want to create it with the properties that every element will have, such as `name`, `email`, etc, without setting any values. I just want to define it with the properties first.

I don't know how many elements I'll need, so I don't want to set it to X number of elements. I just want to be able to add elements as I need them as there's no way to know exactly how many I need.

I hope this makes sense. I'm sure some of my terminology is wrong.

Comment: It sounds as if you want to create a User Defined Object (Class Module) and then add those objects to your Collection or Dictionary.

Comment: If you know what *properties* every element of the *class* will have, you can create as many instances of the class as you'd like, all with the same properties available.